# Typescript eslint does not recognize object in array

Tags: arrays, typescript, next.js, eslint

i got some problem with typescript or eslint (im new in eslint).

**types.ts**

```
export type TSettingsIputsState = {
  personal: {
    label: string;
    name: keyof TApiResponseProfile;
    value: string;
    activeEdit: boolean;
    onActionButtonClick: () => void;
  }[];
  display: boolean;
};
```

**component.tsx**

```
const [profileInputs, setProfileInputs] = useState<TSettingsIputsState>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const setFormData = async () => {
      if (!profileData) return;
      const inputs = await inputsItems();

      setProfileInputs({
        personal: [
          ...inputs.personalSettings.map(({ label, name }) => ({
            label,
            name,
            activeEdit: false,
            value: profileData[name],
            onActionButtonClick: () => console.log("asd"),
          })),
        ],
        display: false,
      });
    };

    setFormData();
  }, [profileData]);
```

This code give me no error from ts or eslint, but when i delete **name** and add **dummy** value, the ts dont suggest me to add name, and dont not recognize that **dummy** shouldn't be there.

```
const [profileInputs, setProfileInputs] = useState<TSettingsIputsState>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const setFormData = async () => {
      if (!profileData) return;
      const inputs = await inputsItems();

      setProfileInputs({
        personal: [
          ...inputs.personalSettings.map(({ label, name }) => ({
            label,
         
            activeEdit: false,
            value: profileData[name],
            onActionButtonClick: () => console.log("asd"),
            dummy: 'test'
          })),
        ],
        display: false,
      });
    };

    setFormData();
  }, [profileData]);
```

Another error is when i change `onActionButtonClick: (testing: string) => void` in type there is no error when no change in  `onActionButtonClick: () => console.log("asd")`

Why no error? doesn't suggest 'name'?

[image]

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "target": "ES2015",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/layouts/*": ["./layouts/*"],
      "@/complex/*": ["./components/complex/*"],
      "@/parts/*": ["./components/parts/*"],
      "@/inputs/*": ["./components/inputs/*"],
      "@/forms/*": ["./components/forms/*"],
      "@/hooks/*": ["./hooks/*"],
      "@/skeletons/*": ["./components/skeletons/*"],
      "@/utils/*": ["./utils/*"],
      "@/middlewares/*": ["./middlewares/*"],
      "@/providers/*": ["./providers/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["./types/*"],
      "@/apiTypes/*": ["./app/api/_types/*"],
      "@/yupSchema/*": ["./yupSchema/*"],
      "@/apiYupSchema/*": ["./app/api/_yupSchema/*"],
      "@/dbPrisma": ["./utils/db.ts"],
      "@/formsInitialValues/*": ["./formsInitialValues/*"],
      "@/wretch": ["./utils/wretch"]

    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "types/**/*.ts", "app/_types/**/*.ts",  "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "__dirname": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"

  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier",
    "@kalimahapps/eslint-plugin-tailwind"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": ["off"],
    "no-unused-vars": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["off"],
    "react/function-component-definition": ["off"],
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": ["off"],
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": ["error"],
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": ["warn"],
    "react/no-array-index-key": ["off"],
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "import/extensions": ["off"],
    "import/prefer-default-export": ["off"],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["off"],
    "@kalimahapps/tailwind/sort": ["warn"],
    "@kalimahapps/tailwind/multiline": ["warn"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": ["off"],
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": ["off"],
    "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": ["off"],
    "no-return-await": ["off"],
    "@typescript-eslint/return-await": ["off"],
    "react/button-has-type": [
      "off",
      {
        "button": true,
        "submit": true,
        "reset": true
      }
    ],
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "return" }
    ]
  }
}
```

It's only happens when **personal** is array, but the error with function parameter check persist anyway.

When i do this, and testing, typescript suggest ok, but not error on function parameter

```
personal: {
    label: string;
    name: keyof TApiResponseProfile;
    value: string;
    activeEdit: boolean;
    onActionButtonClick: (testing: string) => void;
  };
```

Can you guys/girls can check if tsconfig or eslint have some bug?